# How to divide a page into several parts

Tags: css, html

I really wonder how such websites like https://medium.com/ (on the home page) https://qz.com divide the page according to tags or the order is like : header, some news, some articles in same shaped boxes,video, then some more content and then footer... so in one page they are able to show many things.. is that done by dividing page with HTML div tags or is there something else used ? I am a newbie trying to learn Django. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I think there is more than just div-tags, but in the end it is (only) html, css and javascript that creates the visual webside on the clients' side.

Frameworks like the "960 Grid System" or Bootstraps Grid System can help you to keep content in a common order. Create templates for your CMS to achive a common design (Ahhhh: Use a CMS). Maybe use Less, Saas, etc. instead of writing plain old css-files.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Look at their code. Of course you can't see their server-side code, but you can look at the HTML and it clearly shows that medium uses `div`s, while qz uses [`section`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section).

Now as to what you can use, there really isn't anything else. Simply because there isn't any need for it. You might want to add an uniform height for each of those "sections", but you don't need to.

---

Now to the serverside part: they certainly didn't hardcode every single section, but created a template for it. Depending on what technology they use that will look different, but it will always have

1. A template (often called function, template or module depending on the technology used) that has everything ready as to the HTML and CSS. This designs the layout and design of those 'sections'. It also accepts content that it will then insert into that structure.
2. A 'main-page' that uses that template repeatedly, but gives it different information. For Medium this might be something like: `MakeStreamItem("Audio", GetFirstFourAudioItems())`